# Program crashes when using dynamic memory allocation in array

Tags: c

I am given a task which is as follows:
User enters a string of symbols which can be only < (less), > (greater) or = (equal) and string ends with semicolon. The task is to generate numbers between those symbols while the very first number is 1. An example: if user enters <>>>=<; the program should generate numbers according to those symbols, like this: 1<2>1>0>-1=-1<0. In my program everything is working...sort of. Sometimes if I enter 15 symbols, everything works just fine, but when I enter 20 symbols, my program crashes so my guess is I have issues with memory allocation, but not sure where... Any help would be appreciated! Here is my code:

```
Problem solved!
```

Comment: Big wall of Code with non-english names. Please take a look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and remember this site is english.

Comment: Have You tried debugging? [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) for starters. Also, asking for doing Your homework --- isn't the best suited question for StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the variables having non-English names.  The problem is clearly stated.  I also don't see this as a "do my homework" question - the poster has made a pretty clear and reasonably competent effort to do the work and is asking about a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(simboliai)` returns size of the pointer (usually 4) not the actual length of allocated array. You need to keep track of that separately. For example, in another variable.

Comment: I am fairly new to memory allocation and sorry if I might seem stupid, but if I understand you correctly, I should instead of: simboliai=(char*)realloc(simboliai, sizeof(simboliai)+sizeof(char)); just use simboliai=(char*)realloc(simboliai, suma+sizeof(char));? Here suma calculates symbols in string

Comment: Yes. You can also type just `simboliai=realloc(simboliai, suma+1);`. That cast and sizeof are redundant.

Comment: Well, thank you good sir! Tested it out a couple of times with tons of symbols and it works perfectly so far. I guess my problem is solved! :thumbup: